# TikZ: Create a node (PSE-cell)

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, tikz-node

What is the best way to create *one* TikZ-node like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\cellwidth{12mm}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[
Cell/.style={align=center, inner sep=0pt, 
text width=\cellwidth,
minimum height=\cellwidth,
draw=black, fill=purple, 
font=\sffamily
},
]

\node[Cell]{Ba};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Call it `(Ba)`, then add `\node[anchor=north west, inner sep=1pt, font=\small] at (Ba.north west){56};` and so on... ?

Comment: Just for interests: Is there a way to put all the annotations into one node?

Comment: maybe you can put a `tabular` into the node, or a `minipage`. But you will lose flexibility

Comment: Do you know this? https://texample.net/tikz/examples/periodic-table-of-chemical-elements/

Comment: Yes, I know this; but I will make this atomatically with a raw-data-table and a TikZ-matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`labels` can also be written inside `nodes`

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\cell}[7][]{
    \node[minimum size=7em, draw, font=\huge, 
        label={[anchor=north west]north west:#4},
        label={[anchor=north east]north east:#5},
        label={[anchor=south west]south west:#6},
        label={[anchor=south east]south east:#7},
        label={[anchor=south,yshift=3.5ex, font=\small]south:#3},
    #1] (#2) {#2};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\cell[fill=purple]{Ba}{Barium}{137.328}{56}{3.59}{0.89}
\cell[fill=red!30, below=0pt of Ba]{Li}{Litium}{137.328}{56}{3.59}{0.89}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ah, with several labels, I understand.

Answer (score 6):

like this

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,positioning}

\pgfmathsetlengthmacro\cellwidth{12mm}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\cell}[6]{
\node[minimum size=7em,draw,fill=purple] (symb) {\huge #1};
\node[below =0.5em of symb.center]{\small #2};
\node[below left=0em of symb.north east](mass){#3};
\node[below right=0em of symb.north west](nb){#4};
\node[above left=0em of symb.south east](n5){#5};
\node[above right=0em of symb.south west](n6){#6};
}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\cell{Ba}{Barium}{137,328}{56}{3,59}{0,89}


\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]